# Issues getting jpackage to run on a Mac Catalina 10.15.5

Tags: java, macos, command-line-tool, java-14, jpackage

I'm attempting to bundle my Java app into a .dmg file. The plan is to sign and notarize my app for distribution on my website https://strides.co.nz.

I have downloaded Java 14 and have successfully created a path on bash profile. Some java commands are working on Terminal, but whenever I attempt to run jpackage I get "Command not found."

I am not overly familiar with macs and have limited command line knowledge due to being spoiled by Netbeans.  Can someone give me some suggestions on what I am missing.

I am still doing a lot of research on why package will not run on my machine but still have absolutely nothing. I see that jpackage is present in the bin but cannot get it to run. This is what I get on my machine:

```
edwardbullock@Annettes-MacBook-Air ~ % java -version
openjdk version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 14.0.1+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)
edwardbullock@Annettes-MacBook-Air ~ % jpackage --help
zsh: command not found: jpackage
edwardbullock@Annettes-MacBook-Air ~ %
```

I have tried running jpackage on my Windows PC, and jpackage is working on that machine. I seem to be missing something on the mac.

Comment: Do you have some exception or something like that? Command Line Tools downloads the macOS SDK, headers, and build tools such as the Apple LLVM compiler and Make. These tools make it easy to install open source software or develop on UNIX within Terminal.

Comment: I get no exception. Just a message "Command not found". Could that be the response from jpackage if my app configuration isn't correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you have AdoptOpenJDK 14.0.1 running on your machine, this might help:
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jpackage

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I have just downloaded adoptopenjdk and tried again, but still had the same "Command not found" message. There is no acknowledgement the jpackage program is run.

Could it simply be my app configuration not being correct? I was expecting some specific error message or exceptions thrown. Could this be correct? I have worked on my configuration script but still get the same result.